# How do I listen / catch an exception from any page in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, exception

I kind of new to Flutter.

In my Flutter app, I got some services running in the background, for example: updating user profile data or updating contents. Which start to run when the app starts.

And when there is an exception coming from these services, I want to be able to show user a dialog box no matter where the user is in the app (a.k.a: on any page).
Such as when there is a network timeout or some other errors coming from those services which runs in the background.

How do I do this in Flutter?

Since the page doesn't catch the exceptions from these services and I don't want to "inject" all services to all pages.

Comment: see [error_handling](https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/futures-error-handling)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I know how to do error handling according to this article. I have done it and it works well when I'm on the same page or if the class is injected in that page, such as with Bloc. But my question is different. As I have said that these services runs in the background. The user may navigate to different pages but I want to be able to let any page catch the error So that I can get the error message and use the context of the page to show the dialog box. Probably I need to modify the question with a sample code. Will come back with the sample code soon.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
// Pass all uncaught asynchronous errors that aren't handled by the Flutter framework
PlatformDispatcher.instance.onError = (error, stack) {
  debugPrint('PlatformDispatcher.instance.onError: $error  \n stack: $stack');
  return true;
};
```